# Svelte virtual list component - function not working after filtering list

Tags: function, filtering, svelte, svelte-component

I am using the [virtuallist component](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-virtual-list) in a svelte project. I have added filtering to the list. My issue is that a function in my project stops working when I filter the list, I'm assuming because the list item is not yet in the dom when filtered?

The project converts medical units from metric units to international units using two inputs. Changing one input automatically converts the other.
Before filtering, everything works well with conversion but after entering a item name, (e.g. Type Zinc), the input conversion fails in the filtered items. No conversion occurs.
I've looked into afterUpdate as an option but not sure how to implement it.

---------**Added Info** -------------------

The issue is with list items not yet in view. Try typing "zinc" and then changing the input values of Zinc (fails) vs typing Acetone (item already in view) and changing those inputs (it works).

Here is a working [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/8ff332a8839a480c98f846c21231fa8a?version=3.23.0)

The script:

```
 <script>
 import VirtualList from './VirtualList.svelte';
 import unitsH from './data.js';


let searchTerm = "";
let start;
 let end;
  $: filteredList = unitsH.filter(item => item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm) !== -1);

function setBothFromSIH(value, i) {
const {factor, siValue} = unitsH[i];
unitsH[i].siValue = +value;
unitsH[i].usValue = +(value / factor).toFixed(2);
}
function setBothFromUSH(value, i) {
const {factor, usValue} = unitsH[i];
unitsH[i].usValue = +value;
unitsH[i].siValue = +(value * factor).toFixed(2);
 }
  </script>
```

With simplified html code:

```
 <VirtualList items={filteredList} bind:start bind:end let:item >

<div class="border" style="overflow-x: scroll;"> <div><div>

          <div class="name">{item.name}</div>
         <span>Specimen: {item.specimen} </span>
     <span> Conversion Factor: {item.factor} </span>
        </div>
 <div>
  <label>US Range:{item.conventionalRange} {item.conventionalUnit}</label>
           <input  name="us{filteredList.indexOf(item)}" value={item.usValue} on:input="{e => setBothFromUSH(e.target.value, filteredList.indexOf(item))}"  type=number placeholder=" US">

         </div> 
 <div>
 <label>SI Range: {item.siRange} {item.siUnit}</label>
           <input name="si{filteredList.indexOf(item)}" value={item.siValue} on:input="{e => setBothFromSIH(e.target.value, filteredList.indexOf(item))}" type=number placeholder="SI">

         </div></div> </div>
 </VirtualList>

 <p>showing items {start}-{end}</p>
```

Thanks for any help in getting this to work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a small issue with your filter. You convert the product name to lower case but not the filter term ;) If you enter `acetone` instead of `Acetone`, then it works. The fix:

```
$: filteredList = unitsH.filter(item => item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) !== -1);
```

Edit:

The issue with not calling the function for some filtered element is that you display the `filteredList` but still do the lookup on the `unitsH` list. Change it to this and it works:

```
    function setBothFromSIH(value, i) {
        const {factor, siValue} = filteredList[i];
        filteredList[i].siValue = +value;
        filteredList[i].usValue = +(value / factor).toFixed(2);
    }

    function setBothFromUSH(value, i) {
        const {factor, usValue} = filteredList[i];
        filteredList[i].usValue = +value;
        filteredList[i].siValue = +(value * factor).toFixed(2);
    }
```

Happy hacking!

Comment: Thanks , but the issue occurs if you search for an item not yet in view. Try typing  "Zinc" and you will see the issue, no conversion when the input value is changed as it does with Acetone. Filtering works but not the input conversion.

Comment: Works for me, now. Before `Zinc` didn't work (but `zinc` showed two results). After the fix, filtering on `Zinc` also works. At least on the REPL: https://svelte.dev/repl/f8e188dae0ee44cdb42a5fe97940d509?version=3.23.0

Comment: Hmmm, not seeing the inputs working even after emptying cache. The filter always worked (better with your suggestion!) but changing the US input value on Zinc should change the value in the SI input (or vice versa) based on the conversion factor. See my Added info

Comment: I see. Your error description starts getting clearer now. It was not the filter function, it was the conversion.

Comment: @Macsupport Found your bug :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is caused by using the wrong index, in the change handler you pass the index of the item in `filteredIndex` but then you use that one to change the item on that index in the array `unitsH`.

You can see that by:
- start anew
- note the value for Acetaminophen (index 0)
- search zinc
- change value of zinc (index 0 in filtered list)
- clear search

->> acetaminophen has changed because that is index 0 in unitsH

You can easily solve this by passing in the index of the original array instead:

```
<input name="si{filteredList.indexOf(item)}" value={item.siValue} on:input="{e => setBothFromSIH(e.target.value, unitsH.indexOf(item))}" type=number placeholder="SI">
```

However, if you move the markup for each item to a seperate component you can vastly simplify this by directly interacting with the properties instead of trying to change them in the array.